# 'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead adsbygoogle.js:27

Tags: javascript, warnings, adsense

I got this warning when i added google adsense on my site

```
'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead adsbygoogle.js:27
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your code, it seems pretty clear, just use `value` instead of `Attr.nodeValue`.

If you're using a library, try to update it.

Note that `deprecated` means that it may disappear in future version of the code, but should work anyway in your version. If you're not going to modify the library version just take it as a warning.

If you're going to update the libraries, use the new `way` which in this case is using another function that should fulfill the same goal.